# How to Authenticate google api programmatically using php?

Tags: php, google-api

I've just tried "Hello Analytics API" and before getting the data, user is redirected to authentication page.

Is it possible to authenticate programmatically ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't possible. The user has to confirm permissions of the app using the API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How about server to server authentication? Is it possible? I tried it but can't get the token. I am looking for the tutorial for dummy but not found yet.